# using apostrophe's at input() prompt returns error

Tags: python-2.7

After typing "My girl's name" when prompted by the input variable I noticed that every letter after the apostrophe turned green in idle and it returned a syntax error. Although, when I typed in a username and a password with apostrophe's beforehand, it didn't return an error but the letters still turned green in idle.

```
username = input('Type a username: \n>')
password = input('Type a password: \n>')
security question = input('Type a security question: \n>')
```

Comment: `input()` is seldom what you actually want on Python 2.7, as it evaluates your entered text as a Python expression (where an unmatched quote mark is indeed a syntax error).  Try `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: Raw-input removed the error message but why are the letters in idle turning a different color? doesn't that indicate something?